# How can I put this script in a function?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, keyboard

I want to display a text first and remove it after a second, and keep the software running during this time (that is, preventing the loop) and getting the text and display it repeatedly.

I want this to be in the form of a function

I want to display the text with each key and the text operation is in a function

```
import keyboard
import pynput
import tkinter, win32api, win32con, pywintypes
def printer(text):
    label = tkinter.Label(text=text, font=('Times New Roman','16'), fg='white', bg='blue')
    label.master.overrideredirect(True)
    label.master.geometry("+0+0")
    label.master.lift()
    label.master.wm_attributes("-topmost", True)
    label.master.wm_attributes("-disabled", True)
    label.master.wm_attributes("-transparentcolor", "blue")
    hWindow = pywintypes.HANDLE(int(label.master.frame(), 16))
    exStyle = win32con.WS_EX_COMPOSITED | win32con.WS_EX_LAYERED | win32con.WS_EX_NOACTIVATE | win32con.WS_EX_TOPMOST | win32con.WS_EX_TRANSPARENT
    win32api.SetWindowLong(hWindow, win32con.GWL_EXSTYLE, exStyle)
    label.pack()
    label.after(1000, lambda:label.config(text=''))
    label.mainloop()
pressedList = ''
def on_press(key):
    global pressedList
    try:
        pressedKey = key.char # single-char keys
    except:
        pressedKey = key.name # other keys
    pressedList += pressedKey


    if pressedList.rfind('a')+len('a') == len(pressedList) and pressedList[pressedList.rfind('a'):] == 'a':
        printer('a')
    elif pressedList.rfind('f1')+len('f1') == len(pressedList) and pressedList[pressedList.rfind('f1'):] == 'f1' and pressedKey == 'f1':
        printer('f1')
    else:
        printer('pass')
        pass
lis = pynput.keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press)
lis.start()
lis.join()
```

Comment: This website isn't here to write code for you. What have *you* tried. What problems are you encountering with turning this code into a function?

Comment: The function does not work twice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably do not need to mix `tkinter` with other events listeners; binding a `keypress` to a `tkinter` window will do what you require:

```
import tkinter as tk


def display_key(e=None):
    if e is not None:
        tv.set(e.keysym)
        root.after(1000, display_key)
    else:
        tv.set('-')


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('300x200')
tv = tk.StringVar()
tv.set('-')
label = tk.Label(root, textvariable=tv)
label.config(font=("Courier", 144))
label.pack(expand=True, fill='both')

root.bind('<Key>', display_key)

root.mainloop()
```